# How to find out a possible man-in-the-middle the Google way?

Tags: c#, security, ssl, man-in-the-middle

I am wondering how is Google able to show messages like `Cannot connect to the real mail.google.com` or similar? Are the IP addresses of Google servers simply hard-coded within Chrome or is it possible to do a similar thing? This could help making sure clients are not visiting phishing or scams websites.

This errors only shows when trying to access Google related websites, nothing else.

Here is a sample of what Google Chrome shows when trying to connect to Gmail without providing the proxy credentials.

[image]

PS: I usually use C# & ASP.NET. I am open to suggestions.

**EDIT :**

Following the answer from SilverlightFox, is there any way to "request" the pinning of my website certificate? And/Or how to add it to the "STS preloaded list"?

Comment: I would say the IPs are part of Chrome.. since I'm pretty sure Google own some Class A IP ranges.. they won't change.. like, ever.

Comment: I believe chrome uses certificate pinning for google sites.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml

Comment: Certificates. Chrome also does this for MitM attempts on many other websites (and occasionally comes up with false positives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Ted Bigham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000700/how-to-find-out-a-possible-man-in-the-middle-the-google-way#comment33345152_22000700) mentioned in comments, this will be achieved via [Certificate pinning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Certificate_pinning):-

> One way to detect and block many kinds of MITM attacks is "certificate pinning", sometimes called "SSL pinning". A client that does certificate pinning adds an extra step to the normal TLS protocol or SSL protocol: After obtaining the server's certificate in the standard way, the client checks the server's certificate against trusted validation data. Typically the trusted validation data is bundled with the app, in the form of a trusted copy of that certificate, or a trusted hash or fingerprint of that certificate or the certificate's public key. For example, Chromium and **Google Chrome include validation data for the *.google.com certificate that detected fraudulent certificates in 2011**. In other systems the client hopes that the first time it obtains a server's certificate it is trustworthy and stores it; during later sessions with that server, the client checks the server's certificate against the stored certificate to guard against later MITM attacks.

From [What is certificate pinning?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29990/8340):-

> some newer browsers (Chrome, for example) will do a variation of cerficiate pinning using the HSTS mechanism. They preload a specific set of public key hashes into this the HSTS configuration, which limits the valid certificates to only those which indicate the specified public key.

[HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) is a technology that is implemented via a HTTP response header (sent via HTTPS only) that tells a browser to "remember" that a website is to only be accessed via HTTPS for a period of time. If HSTS is set on `www.example.com` and the user  visits `http://www.example.com` before `max-age` has expired, the browser will request `https://www.example.com` instead and no request will be sent via plain HTTP. HSTS requires that the user has already visited the site in order to have received the header, however a workaround has been implemented by Google in their Chrome browser code:

> Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox address this limitation by implementing a "STS preloaded list", which is a list that contains known sites supporting HSTS. This list is distributed with the browser so that it uses HTTPS for the initial request to the listed sites as well.

## Update following question edit

> Following the answer from SilverlightFox, is there any way to "request" the pinning of my website certificate? And/Or how to add it to the "STS preloaded list"?

According to [this blog post](http://blog.stalkr.net/2011/08/hsts-preloading-public-key-pinning-and.html) you should contact the browser developers to be included in the HSTS list and have your public key (or CA's) pinned in the browser:

> is this domain HSTS-preloaded in Chrome? For now it is hardcoded in the binary and will hopefully grow. You can contact Chromium to have your site included in that list.

and

> So right now, the only solution to pin public keys of CAs signing your website certificates would be to contact Chromium team to be included in the code.

Comment: Very interesting thanks! Please have a look at the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fight the man-in-the-middle is to have some pre-shared knowledge. In this case those are hardcoded certificates of a couple of root authorities that your browser trusts. These root certificates are used by their authority to sign certificates of other authorities which in turn become trustworthy too. A chain of trust is built until you hit the certificate of mail.google.com.

When you go to mail.google.com you are automatically redirected to the HTTPS (note the **S**!) version of the site. HTTPS means certificates. Your browser downloads the certificate of that site and inspects if the signing chain is rooted by some of the authorities your browser trusts. If not: Big fat warning! Possibly man-in-the-middle spoof going on!

Another thing that might happen is that the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS fails because some firewall between you and Google blocks HTTPS. That might be the warning you are getting.